# GKE cluster shutdown

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, scale

Want to stop GKE cluster while cluster is not in use on night time or weekend. Approach should be like workload will not be hampered. Once I scale up it should run fine . Tell me the process of it if anyone has done this task.

Answer (score 1):

GKE clusters cannot be stopped once they are created. However, if you want to scale down the number of nodes during weekends and then scale them back up on weekdays, you can use Cloud Scheduler to schedule a job to run a command that changes the number of nodes.

There are some tutorials, you may check them out.

[Scaling down Google Kubernetes cluster to zero during off-peak hours](https://bhabalajinkya.medium.com/scaling-down-google-kubernetes-cluster-to-zero-during-off-peak-hours-4281b464d14e)

[Scaling nodes in Kubernetes on a schedule.](https://maherrahman1.medium.com/scaling-nodes-in-kubernetes-on-a-schedule-24f991529e96)

[Programmatically switch off the nodes in a GKE cluster with Cloud Scheduler](https://medium.com/@iobluedot/programmatically-switch-off-the-nodes-in-a-gke-cluster-with-cloud-scheduler-6c705b279377)